# MySQL calculating row differences with unstructured data

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table messages with columns: phonenumber, type, timestamp.
Type indicates if the message is a question or an answer.

Now I need a query that can calculate the response time between a question and an answer but the problem is that there exists no relationship between question & answer except for the fact that they have the same phone number.

So these 2 records belong together:

```
Phonenumber | Type     | Timestamp  
  123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
  123456789 | Answer   | xxxxxx
```

- It's possible that there are multiple questions from the same phonenumber before an answer is send to that phonenumber. In that case the timestamp from the last message should be used:

  ```
  Phonenumber | Type     | Timestamp  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  <-  
    123456789 | Answer   | xxxxxx
  ```
- It is not Q -> A, Q -> A in the database, so something like this is possible:

  ```
  Phonenumber | Type     | Timestamp  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
    987654321 | Question | xxxxxx  
    987654321 | Answer   | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Answer   | xxxxxx
  ```
- 1 Phonenumber can have multiple sets of Q -> A. All these sets should be in the calculation:

  ```
  Phonenumber | Type     | Timestamp  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Answer   | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Question | xxxxxx  
    123456789 | Answer   | xxxxxx
  ```

To be honest I have no idea how to even start on this. I have found some things about calculating the difference between 2 rows but than I will need to have my data completely structured first. (Q -> A, Q -> A, Q -> A, ...).

I know it would be much easier if there would be a relationship defined between a Q and the corresponding A but that's not available :/

SQL Fiddle link unstructured data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dff3/1/0
SQL Fiddle link structured data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61a62/1/0
Once I have this I can calculate the average response time by calculating the timestamp different between row2-row1, row4-row3, row6-row5.

UPDATE:
`SELECT t1.answer AS answer, t1.timeOfAnswer AS timeOfAnswer, MIN(t1.responseTime) AS responseTime 
    FROM (
    SELECT
      a.message AS answer,
      a.timestamp AS timeOfAnswer,
      timestampdiff(second, q.timestamp, a.timestamp) AS responseTime 
    FROM message q 
    JOIN message a ON q.phoneNumber = a.phoneNumber 
    WHERE q.type = 0 AND a.type = 1
    HAVING responseTime > 0
  ) AS t1
  GROUP BY t1.answer`
With this query it works fine on my sample data because the message content is named like 'Message 1 answer', 'Message 2 answer', ... So I can do GROUP BY on that field. But on the real data it's possible that the same answer gets send multiple times.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Oh, and the fact that they share a telephone number (and one is dated after the other), that *IS* a relationship!

Comment: For the second example, you don't state what should be done.

Comment: I have added 2 SQL Fiddle links at the bottom of my first post. In the second example the response time should be calculated between row 1 & row 4 and between row 2 & row 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is 100% correct but it may be a useful start:

```
select q0.message, max(q0.tsd) from 
(
   select m0.message, timestampdiff(second, m0.timestamp, m1.timestamp) as tsd 
   from message m0 
   join message m1 on m0.phoneNumber = m1.phoneNumber 
   where m0.type = 1 and m1.type = 0
   having tsd < 0
) as q0  
group by message;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dff3/21) to experiment with.

Comment: I adjusted your query a bit (see first post, I can't figure out how to format code decently in here + it's too long).
On my sample data it works perfect because the message answers are named 'Message 1 answer', 'Message 2 answer', ... But if you send the same answer multiple times to different question it won't work anymore. (the GROUP BY). Any suggestions?

Comment: Stupid of me, I can just order by the ID of the answer instead of the actual message itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query posted by ethrbunny (thank you so much!).
I think this is the solution:

```
SELECT 
  t1.answerId AS answerId, 
  t1.answer AS answer, 
  t1.timeOfAnswer AS timeOfAnswer, 
  MIN(t1.responseTime) AS responseTime 
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.id AS answerId,
    a.message AS answer,
    a.timestamp AS timeOfAnswer,
    timestampdiff(second, q.timestamp, a.timestamp) AS responseTime 
  FROM message q 
  JOIN message a ON q.phoneNumber = a.phoneNumber 
  WHERE q.type = 0 AND a.type = 1
  HAVING responseTime > 0
) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.answerId
```